# Propel WHERE IN clause and MySQL function

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

Recently I have started coding with Symfony and Propel 2.x, and I came across a problem with WHERE IN clause.

I want to get clients that was born in 1993 and 1988.

So I have written this Propel Query code fragment:

```
$query = ClientQuery::create()
    ->where('YEAR(Client.Birthdate) IN ?', [1993, 1988])
    ->find();
```

... and the ORM mapped these integers as DateTime object, so final query look like:

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.user_id, clients.first_name, clients.last_name, clients.birthdate, clients.document_id, clients.street, clients.postal_code, clients.city, clients.country 
FROM clients 
WHERE YEAR(clients.birthdate) IN ('1970-01-01','1970-01-01')
```

Is there way to use Propel to build query like below, without using RAW SQL query?

```
SELECT clients.id, clients.user_id, clients.first_name, clients.last_name, clients.birthdate, clients.document_id, clients.street, clients.postal_code, clients.city, clients.country 
    FROM clients 
    WHERE YEAR(clients.birthdate) IN (1993, 1988)
```

I have tried add `YEAR(clients.birthdate)` to SELECT with alias but also I can't get expected query.

Comment: What type of column is birthdate in the clients table? Can you show some data stored it int?

Comment: @m1n0 this column is DATE type. Propel thinks that i'm comparing DATEs instead of INT, so it cast my values to DateTime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You could try to specify the binding type:

    ->where('YEAR(Client.Birthdate) IN ?', [1993, 1988], PDO::PARAM_INT)</del>

Edit:

Yes, you are right. This solution will result in a PropelException, because Propel/PDO can not bind an array to int.

Alternatively you could use OR conditions:

```
  $years = [1993, 1988];
  // Get the key of the first element
  $firstKey = key($years);
  $query = ClientQuery::create();
  foreach ($years as $key => $year) {
      // Add _or() call for all elements except the first one
      if ($key !== $firstKey) {
          $query->_or();
      }
      // Add where condition and binding type
      $query->where('YEAR(Client.Birthdate) = ?', $year, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  }
  $query = $query->find();
```

I would agree that this solution does not look very nice, but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Got PropelException:
`
Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT clients.id, clients.user_id, clients.first_name, clients.last_name, clients.birthdate, clients.document_id, clients.street, clients.postal_code, clients.city, clients.country FROM clients WHERE YEAR(clients.birthdate) IN :p1]
`

Comment: This solution cannot take advantage of any indexes on the birthdate field.

Comment: Raw SQL in an ORM query... Wouldn&#39;t it be better to use either raw SQL without Propel or figure out how to do this query in Propel without raw SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like you're going to have to use 4 conditions:

- birthdate >= '1993-01-01' AND birthdate < '1994-01-01'
- OR birthdate >= '1988-01-01' AND birthdate < '1989-01-01'

You can do this by using the `condition()` and `combine()` methods of the `ClientQuery` class.

http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#combining-several-conditions

I would advise against using the `_or()` method.

Also, I would bet using unix timestamps would make your application logic to build the query easier.